# replace links in string with my link

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, string, url

i want to replace every link(s) in a string with the link i want to provide. What i have tried is-

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
Regex regx = new Regex("http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string output=regx.ToString();
output = readFile;
MatchCollection matches = regx.Matches(output);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    output = output.Replace(@"match.Value", @"http://localhost:61187/two?" + "sender=" + Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text) + "&reciever=" + output);
}
```

Here, i have a string output which contains some links. So, i have used regex to parse the links in the string. But, the string named "output" is not read and  its neither showing an error nor an output.

Comment: What is `dd1.SelectedItem.Value`? Does it return an open `Stream` at position 0 (or the correct position to start reading from), or the path to a file to read?

Comment: please share some example of values in dd1.SelectedItem.Value.

Comment: it returns the html page which is being selected from the dropdown

Comment: `@"match.Value"` isn't using `match.Value` as a variable, it is looking for "match.Value" (string literal) in `output`. Regardless, why not use `regex.Replace(...)` ?

Comment: its returning- "F:\\projects\\mailer\\mailer\\App_Data\\one.html"

Comment: i don't know how to use a regex to get the urls in my string. All i am concerned about is read my string and if it contains any url(s), then i want to replace them with my page url and pass the name of the urls in the string to that page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you should be using `regx.Replace(...)` instead:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dd1.SelectedItem.Value);
string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
Regex regx = new Regex("http(s)?://([\\w+?\\.\\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\\~\\!\\@\\#\\$\\%\\^\\&amp;\\*\\(\\)_\\-\\=\\+\\\\\\/\\?\\.\\:\\;\\'\\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\\?\\#\\=\\/]){1})?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string output = regx.ToString();
output = readFile;
string username = Server.UrlEncode(this.txtUsername.Text);
output = regx.Replace(output, new MatchEvaluator((match) =>
{
    var url = Uri.EscapeDataString(match.Value);
    return $"http://localhost:61187/two?sender={username}&receiver={url}";
}));
```

This will replace every match with the URL returned by the anonymous function.

Comment: harsha, this answers your question. Images use links too, so your regex is also matching them. If this is an issue for you, then you ought to post a _new question_ focusing specifically on the issue of the regular expression matching image URLs.

Comment: i have used this but the images in the html page vanished as the contained src tag like-  <img src="http://www.exa123t.in/tele/images/next.jpg">

Comment: what if i don't want to replace the links of images

Comment: Then you need to fix your regular expression, but that's a different question and should be posted as a new question.

Comment: can't you help me out if you know the solution?

Comment: @harsha try prefixing your regex with a negative lookbehind `(?<!src=\\")` (or if you just want to match `href="` then you can use a positive lookbehind: `(?<=href=\\")`)

Comment: its showing error-       parsing "?< !src =\)http(s)?://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*([a-zA-Z0-9\?\#\=\/]){1})?" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.      I have no clue about regex as i haven't used it earlier

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy it in full.

Comment: can you just provide the complete regex statement